# Limit people picker to a certain group

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath2010

Is there a way to limit the people picker control in InfoPath to a certain SharePoint group? I need to do this without writing any code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can, here a great response on the sharepoint stackexchange site

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/38019/in-infopath-limit-people-picker-to-a-certain-sharepoint-group